# Connecting angular to azure service bus - MEAN stack

Tags: node.js, angular, azure-functions, mean-stack, azureservicebus

How does one connect an angular app to azure service bus?

With a nodejs backend, what should Angular do to make that connection?

Answer (score 3):

It's not entirely clear if you are trying to connect your Angular front end to Service Bus as a replacement for SignalR. If so, it isn't a good idea as it would create a serious security hole. Service Bus is primarily for communication between servers. In this scenario, if you had multiple back end node servers, you could use Service Bus to sync the data they are pushing to your clients.

You are going in a better direction with SignalR. The technology you are looking for in real time server-browser communication is [websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API). SignalR is just a .NET implementation of that standard. Once you start looking for websocket implementations on the MEAN stack, you should have a lot more success in finding guides. Here's a couple for generic JS implentations just as an example: [Link 1](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/getting-started-with-node-js-and-websockets-f22dd0452105) [Link 2](https://flaviocopes.com/node-websockets/).

**Edit for comment response:**
You don't want to connect angular to Service Bus at all. Once you've exposed the keys publically, anyone can read/write whatever they want to your bus. Instead have Angular send the message to a HTTP function and have the function [send the message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus) to Service Bus.

The second problem with this plan is that websockets connections, the part that pushes data back to the client, is a long-running connection with constant communication back and forth. The consumption and premium plans [are not built](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/738) for this. Trying to use websockets on those plans will run up your costs a lot higher than they need to be if you have any significant traffic. You'll need to choose a plan that has a flat monthly cost instead. At that point you could still use Functions, but it may be easier to use a traditional web app.

In this case your system would look like this: 
`Angular new message -> HTTP Function/Web App -> Service Bus -> Websocket Function/Web app => Angular`
If you are only running a single server, you can eliminate Service Bus completely.

The other option is to still use a HTTP function to receive new messages, but then [use the SignalR service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-concept-azure-functions) (not the .NET library) to handle pushing the data to the clients. This elimiates Service Bus as well.
This is what it would look like: `Angular new message -> HTTP Function/Web App -> SignalR Service->Angular`

Comment: I plan on using azure functions to handle subscribing and publishing to service bus. I'm just trying to figure out how Angular's role in all this works. Would I use this library in angular and send the data to a queue and receive data without page reload? https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/service-bus Then use an azure function service bus queue trigger function to grab data from queue using nodejs service bus sdk and update data for that topic? Then maybe ```Receive a message``` section in that library allows me to get that updated data without page reload. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Would SignalR be the cost effective solution if I'm using storage blob for the angular frontend? Websockets I fear would be way more costly. Also if I had 10 auction listings showing up on a page at a time. Does SignalR only register 1 connection since it's 1 user or would that = 10 connections?

Comment: 1 browser session = 1 connection. A user could have multiple connections if they are using multiple tabs in their browser.

If you want real time in Angular, then you want to use websockets, whether or not you are using the SignalR implementation. Think of websockets like a car and SignalR as a Ford or Honda- it's a specific type of car.

Comment: It's not true real time, but you could set up a timer in Angular to refresh the data regularly.  That would let you use a standard HTTP Function to retrieve the latest data. If a delay of something like 30 seconds or a minute is acceptable, than this would be a viable alternative.

Comment: If I'm using azure functions then wouldn't I have to use something like azure event grid in order to get signalr changes to frontend? This way I wouldn't be using websockets. And followup question, can I use event grid instead of signalr or do they need to be used together if at all?

Comment: Also I've been going through different git repos to see examples and one thing I see is them all initiating a connection like this one: https://github.com/GrillPhil/ServerlessRealtimeDemo/blob/master/angular/src/app/signalr.service.ts  Isn't this technically a websocket since it's keeping an open connection to send updated data back to other clients?

Comment: If you are trying to make a real time web page you have two options:
1) Use a persistent connection via websockets
2) Have the client regularly poll for near-real time data.
Those are your only two options. SignalR is not a seperate technology, it's just a library that makes using websockets easier. The Azure service uses the SignalR library, it just implements the code for you so you don't have to manage that portion.

Comment: Event Grid, like Service Bus, is primarily meant for service to service communication, it just uses a different mechanism. It is not capable of pushing data to a browser since it needs a static endpoint to send data to.

Answer (score 0):

NPM has a package which can handle Service Bus. Check out the robust documentation for the service bus package:

[@azure/service-bus - npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/service-bus)

which has examples and also lists how to get things working with the different packages.